Rsolve is not working (a(n) too difficult to find?)
   RSolve[{a[n] ==2(N*3^n+Sum[3^(n-1-j)*a[j],{j,0,n-1}])-Sum[2^(k+1)*(floor[(2*(N*3^n+Sum[3^(n-1-j)*a[j],{j,0,n-1}])-1+2^(k+1))/2^(k+2)]-
floor[(2*(N*3^n+Sum[3^(n-1-j)*a[j],{j,0,n-1}])-1+2^(k+2))/2^(k+3)]-floor[(N*3^n+Sum[3^(n-1-j)*a[j],{j,0,n-1}])/2^(k+2)]),{k,0,floor[log[N*3^n+Sum[3^(n-1-j)*a[j],{j,0,n-1}]]/log[2]]}],a[0]==1}, a[n], n]

I'm trying to find an explicit formula of the succession a(n), but unsuccessfully. Rsolve[] does not work, it gives me the same equation, without solving it.
It's probably because a(n) it's too complicated to find. How can i use Mathematica to find the exact formula of a(n)?

N is a built-in function.  use Floor , Log.

Even with these errors corrected, this recurrence equation probably is too difficult for RSolve.

@bbgodfrey, this is explained in the Possible Issues for Floor, and FullSimplify[Floor[Log[16]/Log[2]]] works.

So it is.  Thanks.

Although RSolve is unable to solve the recurrence relation, even for nn (replacing N in the question) specified.  However,a[n] can be computed numerically by modifying the code in the question to
sol[nn_] := Module[{a}, a[0] = 1;
      a[n_] := a[n] = 2 (nn*3^n + Sum[3^(n - 1 - j)*a[j], {j, 0, n - 1}]) - 
      Sum[2^(k + 1)*(Floor@FullSimplify[(2*(nn*3^n + 
      Sum[3^(n - 1 - j)*a[j], {j, 0, n - 1}]) - 1 + 2^(k + 1))/2^(k + 2)] - 
      Floor@FullSimplify[(2*(nn*3^n + Sum[3^(n - 1 - j)*a[j], {j, 0, n - 1}]) - 
      1 + 2^(k + 2))/2^(k + 3)] - 
      Floor@FullSimplify[(nn*3^n + Sum[3^(n - 1 - j)*a[j], {j, 0, n - 1}])
      /2^(k + 2)]), 
      {k, 0, Floor@FullSimplify[Log[nn*3^n + Sum[3^(n - 1 - j)*a[j], {j, 0, n - 1}]]
      /Log[2]]}];
  Table[a[n], {n, 0, 10}]]

Modifications address the issues raised in comments above.  Solutions for nn an even integer all are, as illustrated for nn = 0,
sol[0] 
(* {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2} *)

while solutions for several even integer nn,
  Table[sol[i], {i, 1, 21, 2}]
(* {{1, 4, 16, 64, 256, 1024, 4096, 16384, 65536, 262144, 1048576}, 
    {1, 2, 32, 128, 512, 2048, 8192, 32768, 131072, 524288, 2097152}, 
    {1, 16, 64, 256, 1024, 4096, 16384, 65536, 262144, 1048576, 4194304}, 
    {1, 2, 4, 16, 128, 2048, 8192, 32768, 131072, 524288, 2097152}, 
    {1, 4, 8, 16, 64, 512, 8192, 32768, 131072, 524288, 2097152}, 
    {1, 2, 8, 64, 1024, 4096, 16384, 65536, 262144, 1048576, 4194304}, 
    {1, 8, 128, 512, 2048, 8192, 32768, 131072, 524288, 2097152, 8388608},
    {1, 2, 4, 8, 256, 4096, 16384, 65536, 262144, 1048576, 4194304}, 
    {1, 4, 32, 512, 2048, 8192, 32768, 131072, 524288, 2097152, 8388608}, 
    {1, 2, 16, 32, 128, 1024, 16384, 65536, 262144, 1048576, 4194304}, 
    {1, 64, 256, 1024, 4096, 16384, 65536, 262144, 1048576, 4194304, 16777216}} *)

After the first few values of a[n], subsequent values increase by a factor of four over the preceding values, i.e., a[j] = 4 a[j-1].  Incidentally, I performed this analysis in the hope that a simple symbolic solution would become visible but was only partly successful.
Edit: Here is a simpler and faster version of the code.
sol[nn_] := Module[{a, sa}, a[0] = 1; a[n_] := 
    a[n] = (sa = nn*3^n + Sum[3^(n - 1 - j)*a[j], {j, 0, n - 1}]; 
    2 sa - Sum[2^(k + 1)*(Floor[(2 sa - 1 + 2^(k + 1))/2^(k + 2)] 
    - Floor[(2 sa - 1 + 2^(k + 2))/2^(k + 3)] 
    - Floor[sa/2^(k + 2)]), {k, 0, Floor[Log[2, sa]]}]);
  Table[a[n], {n, 0, 10}]]


hi! thank you for simplyfing the equation. it actually make sense since another user found out that a[n] behaves as 4^n. thanks a lot!

Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign, and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.
